# How to modify select rows in the same column from all nested lists within a list?

Tags: r

I have a nested list of items such that I have 3 separate lists grouped into one. I would like to make changes to a specific column that is present in all the lists. I have more details below

> X

```
  $`Sports`
    Name    Start.Date
    Hockey  2019-07-01
    Soccer  2019-07-01
    Tennis  2019-07-01
    Track   2019-07-01

  $`Course`
    Name    Start.Date
    Math    2019-07-01
    English 2019-07-01
    Biology 2019-07-01
    Spanish 2019-07-01
    Physics 2019-07-01

  $`Elective`
    Name    Start.Date
    Ballet  2019-07-01
    Arts    2019-07-01
    Chess   2019-07-01
    Piano   2019-07-01
    Dance   2019-07-01
    Flute   2019-07-01
    Reading 2019-07-01
```

I want to only modify the 'Start.Date' column

> lapply(X, '[', 'Start.Date') gives me:

```
  $`Sports`
    Start.Date
    2019-07-01
    2019-07-01
    2019-07-01
    2019-07-01

  $`Course`
    Start.Date
    2019-07-01
    2019-07-01
    2019-07-01
    2019-07-01
    2019-07-01

  $`Elective`
    Start.Date
    2019-07-01
    2019-07-01
    2019-07-01
    2019-07-01
    2019-07-01
    2019-07-01
    2019-07-01
```

However would like to keep the date of only the first row in each list Item so it appears like this:

```
  $`Sports`
    Name    Start.Date
    Hockey  2019-07-01
    Soccer  NA
    Tennis  NA
    Track   NA

  $`Course`
    Name    Start.Date
    Math    2019-07-01
    English NA
    Biology NA
    Spanish NA
    Physics NA

  $`Elective`
    Name    Start.Date
    Ballet  2019-07-01
    Arts    NA
    Chess   NA
    Piano   NA
    Dance   NA
    Flute   NA
    Reading NA
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible approaches:

```r
library(tidyverse)

X <- list(
  Sports = data.frame(
    Name = c("Hockey", "Soccer", "Tennis", "Track"),
    Start.Date = rep(as.Date("2019-07-01"), 4)
  ),
  Course = data.frame(
    Name = c("Math", "English", "Biology", "Spanish", "Physics"),
    Start.Date = rep(as.Date("2019-07-01"), 5)
  ),
  Elective = data.frame(
    Name = c("Ballet", "Arts", "Chess", "Piano", "Dance", "Flute", "Reading"),
    Start.Date = rep(as.Date("2019-07-01"), 7)
  )
)

X
#> $Sports
#>     Name Start.Date
#> 1 Hockey 2019-07-01
#> 2 Soccer 2019-07-01
#> 3 Tennis 2019-07-01
#> 4  Track 2019-07-01
#> 
#> $Course
#>      Name Start.Date
#> 1    Math 2019-07-01
#> 2 English 2019-07-01
#> 3 Biology 2019-07-01
#> 4 Spanish 2019-07-01
#> 5 Physics 2019-07-01
#> 
#> $Elective
#>      Name Start.Date
#> 1  Ballet 2019-07-01
#> 2    Arts 2019-07-01
#> 3   Chess 2019-07-01
#> 4   Piano 2019-07-01
#> 5   Dance 2019-07-01
#> 6   Flute 2019-07-01
#> 7 Reading 2019-07-01

X %>%
  map(
    . %>% 
      mutate(
        Start.Date = c(Start.Date[1], rep(NA, length(Start.Date) - 1))
      )
  )
#> $Sports
#>     Name Start.Date
#> 1 Hockey 2019-07-01
#> 2 Soccer       <NA>
#> 3 Tennis       <NA>
#> 4  Track       <NA>
#> 
#> $Course
#>      Name Start.Date
#> 1    Math 2019-07-01
#> 2 English       <NA>
#> 3 Biology       <NA>
#> 4 Spanish       <NA>
#> 5 Physics       <NA>
#> 
#> $Elective
#>      Name Start.Date
#> 1  Ballet 2019-07-01
#> 2    Arts       <NA>
#> 3   Chess       <NA>
#> 4   Piano       <NA>
#> 5   Dance       <NA>
#> 6   Flute       <NA>
#> 7 Reading       <NA>

lapply(X, function(df) { 
  transform(df, Start.Date = c(Start.Date[1], rep(NA, length(Start.Date) - 1))) 
})
#> $Sports
#>     Name Start.Date
#> 1 Hockey 2019-07-01
#> 2 Soccer       <NA>
#> 3 Tennis       <NA>
#> 4  Track       <NA>
#> 
#> $Course
#>      Name Start.Date
#> 1    Math 2019-07-01
#> 2 English       <NA>
#> 3 Biology       <NA>
#> 4 Spanish       <NA>
#> 5 Physics       <NA>
#> 
#> $Elective
#>      Name Start.Date
#> 1  Ballet 2019-07-01
#> 2    Arts       <NA>
#> 3   Chess       <NA>
#> 4   Piano       <NA>
#> 5   Dance       <NA>
#> 6   Flute       <NA>
#> 7 Reading       <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot!.